# Confusing behaviour between class and object

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Since we know that class is also an object of class Class. I have a doubt here.
I have a class defined here Foo and a method which prints the object.

```
class Foo
  def bar
    puts self
  end
    puts self
end
```

When I do Foo.new.bar o/p will be `# <Foo:0x935c740>` 
which represents an object of class Foo.
Why not the self outside the method prints `#<Class: 0x..>` as its an object of class Class?
Sorry if my question is wrong but please clarify it.

Comment: After the line `class Foo` is parsed, `self` is `Foo` and `puts self` is executed before the parsing of the class is complete. `puts self` therefore prints `Foo`.  Later, when you create the instance and invoke `bar` on it, `self` is the instance of `Foo` and that is therefore what is printed.

Comment: Read it thoroughly.. http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a little different way to define a classes/objects:

```
klass = Class.new {
  puts self
  def bar
    puts self
  end
}
# #<Class:0x3fbdbb8>
```

As you can see, it outputs `#<Class:0x3fbdbb8>`. So its class is `Class`. You can check it via `class` method:

```
klass.class
# => Class
```

When you name your class with uppercase letter (for example `Example`) for the first time, it use it as output instead of cryptic name like: `#<Class:0x3fbdbb8>`.

```
Foo = Class.new {
  puts self
  def bar
    puts self
  end
}
```

Still outputs cryptic name because `Foo =`'s part hasn't been evaluated **yet**.

```
puts Foo
```

Outputs correct name - `Foo`

#### What if I name it again?

```
Qux = Foo
# => Foo
```

Nothing. `Foo` will be `Foo` forever.

Answer (score 3):

Names of classes and modules are constant in ruby. So when you are defining a class you are creating an object of class Class and providing it with a constant name and hence when you do a `puts self` in a class context, it gives a class name instead of something like `#<Class: 0x..>`